# Type mismatch error when types are verified

Tags: excel, vba

This OutputAgedEntries takes in a dictionary<string,collection < MaterialTicket> >. I get a type mismatch error when calling OutputEntry with the first signature below. If I instead try to run it with the second signature, it runs just fine and does get called inside of that type checking if statement. So if Vendor and Entry are verified as being string and MaterialTicket, why do I get a type mismatch error with the first function signature?

```
Function OutputAgedEntries(AgedEntries As Dictionary)
    Dim NumVendors As Long: NumVendors = 0
    Dim Line As Long
    For Each Vendor In AgedEntries.Keys
        Line = 2
        For Each Entry In AgedEntries(Vendor)
            Dim VendorType As String
            VendorType = TypeName(Vendor)
            Dim EntryType As String
            EntryType = TypeName(Entry)
            If (VendorType = "String" And EntryType = "MaterialTicket") Then
                Call OutputEntry(Entry, NumVendors, Line, Vendor)
            End If
            Line = Line + 1
        Next Entry
    Next Vendor
End Function

Function OutputEntry(Entry As MaterialTicket, NumVendors As Long, Line As Long, Vendor As String)

Function OutputEntry(Entry, NumVendors As Long, Line As Long, Vendor)
```

Comment: That is because you have not defined `Entry` and `Vendor` in `Function OutputAgedEntries(AgedEntries As Dictionary)` as the expected type. My recommendation. Use `Option Explicit` at the top which will force you to declare variables.

Comment: So I tried implementing that and declaring Vendor as string generates "For Each control variable must be variant or object"

Comment: Then change `Function OutputEntry(...Vendor As String)` to `Function OutputEntry(...Vendor As Variant)`

Comment: That technically gets it to work, but doesn't seem like a great solution since all sorts of stuff can be passed in, especially since I am keying worksheet names to Vendor and is essentially the same as just running with the second signature.

Comment: Let me see if I can explain it in a logical way? You have created a round hole so that you can pass a cylindrical object through it but you now want to pass a cube through that space? If you have specified that the parameter has to be of type `MaterialTicket` then your function will not accept a `Variant` parameter. If your procedure needs it to be a variant then your function needs to accept it as variant.

Comment: I think you're missing the nature of my question. When I run the code with the first signature, I get a type mismatch. When I run it with the second signature the function gets called which can only happen if I am sending in a MaterialTicket due to the type checking implemented and therefore there should not have been a type mismatch error with the first signature.